# while running the command npx react-native run-android , its showing error like this ,

Tags: react-native

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Unable to start the daemon process.
  This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
  For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
  Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
  Process command line: C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenLogic\jre-8.0.382.05-hotspot\bin\java.exe -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=IN -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\HP.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-8.0.1-all\aro4hu1c3oeioove7l0i4i14o\gradle-8.0.1\lib\gradle-launcher-8.0.1.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 8.0.1
  Please read the following process output to find out more:

---

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

tried cleaning and rebuild the app but still showing the same error